# Why the weighted least square $R^2$ from R summary doesn't match my manual calculation

Tags: r, regression, r-squared, weighted-regression

I have a weighted least square model and I wanted to calculate $R^2$ manually, but my results don't match the R summary. Why is that?

```
> head(weights(m))
[1] 0.973411 0.408694 0.414370 0.426554 0.357159 0.407986
> yhat = predict(m)
> y = as.numeric(model.frame(m)[,1])
> SStot = sum((y - mean(y))^2)
> SSres = sum((y - yhat)^2)
> rsq = 1 - (SSres / SStot)
> rsq
[1] 0.065211
> summary(m)$r.squared
[1] 0.0433978
```

The same formulas give me the correct $R^2$ when using ordinary least square.

Comment: Could you point out where you are manually computing a *weighted* $R^2$? I don't see any use of the weights at all in your example.

Comment: I don't. I thought the formula was the same. So if weights have to be used, I'm not clear why. $R^2$ quantifies the explained variance. Why would we care about how the observations were weighted?

Comment: If you don't care about how the observations are weighted, then why are you specifying weights in your model?  Ultimately, the correct formula to use depends on what the weights mean.  What do you intend them to represent?

Comment: I care about the weights only to calculate the coefficients. Once my estimates have been calculated I want to relate different models (WLS or OLS) using the same formula.

Comment: For reference, this [thread](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83826/is-a-weighted-r2-in-robust-linear-model-meaningful-for-goodness-of-fit-analys) answers my question.

Comment: Thank you for finding that, Robert.  It clarifies your question, too.  I am glad you found an answer here.