# Can't replicate $R^2$ from a weighted regression in R

Tags: r, r-squared, lm, weights

I need to calculate the $R^2$ for a specific regression model in R, since the specific function I'm using doesn't return it. I'm trying to do so based on [this excellent answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/87085/162522), but am still unable to replicate the results I get using lm. Below, a minimal example based on a slice of my actual data.

Note: I understand my $R^2$ may be misleadingly high, since I'm running a model without an intercept. Regardless, I can't replicate R's output even when I include the intercept.

```
> # A slice of my data
> df
# A tibble: 20 x 3
         y x         w
     <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
 1  0.212  c     1.44 
 2  0.419  c     0.758
 3 -0.579  c     1.38 
 4 -0.523  a     0.419
 5 -0.833  a     0.610
 6 -0.686  a     2.06 
 7 -0.173  a     1    
 8  0.0649 c     1.16 
 9 -1.04   b     0.753
10 -0.913  b     2.46 
11  0.189  a     1    
12 -0.382  c     1    
13 -0.770  b     1    
14 -0.611  b     0.392
15 -0.536  c     1    
16 -0.199  a     1    
17 -0.968  b     0.631
18 -1.89   b     1    
19 -0.511  c     0.898
20  0.581  c     0.775
> 
> # Regression without intercept
> reg <- lm(y ~ 0 + x, df, weights = w)
> summary(reg)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ 0 + x, data = df, weights = w)

Weighted Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.8385 -0.3569  0.1230  0.2743  0.6189 

Coefficients:
   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
xa  -0.3816     0.1729  -2.206   0.0414 *  
xb  -1.0475     0.1710  -6.125 1.12e-05 ***
xc  -0.1226     0.1472  -0.833   0.4164    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4269 on 17 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7171,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6671 
F-statistic: 14.36 on 3 and 17 DF,  p-value: 6.481e-05

> 
> # Calculating R^2
> rss <- sum((reg$residuals * df$w)^2)
> tss <- sum((df$y * df$w - weighted.mean(df$y, df$w))^2)
> 1-rss/tss
[1] 0.6502406
> 
> 
> # I can't replicate the results even when I include the intercept
> reg2 <- lm(y ~ x, df, weights = w)
> summary(reg2)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = df, weights = w)

Weighted Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.8385 -0.3569  0.1230  0.2743  0.6189 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  -0.3816     0.1729  -2.206   0.0414 *
xb           -0.6660     0.2432  -2.738   0.0140 *
xc            0.2590     0.2271   1.140   0.2699  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4269 on 17 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5034,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.445 
F-statistic: 8.616 on 2 and 17 DF,  p-value: 0.002607

> 
> # Calculating R^2
> rss <- sum((reg2$residuals * df$w)^2)
> tss <- sum((df$y * df$w - weighted.mean(df$y, df$w))^2)
> 1-rss/tss
[1] 0.6502406
```

### Edit

As pointed out by @whuber, I had en error in my rss formula. I then went and looked at the code for summary.lm. It calculates the $r^2$ using the mean sum of squares, rather than the total sum of squares. I can, thus, replicate R's results if I use the mss, rather than the tss. What I still don't understand is that, theoretically, the TSS should be equal to RSS + MSS, but I'm not getting that. Code below:

```
> # I can replicate it when I use the mean sum of squares
> rss <- sum(df$w * reg$residuals^2)
> mss <- sum(df$w * reg$fitted.values^2)
> mss/(rss + mss)
[1] 0.7170557
> 
> # or, alternatively
> 1-rss/(rss+mss)
[1] 0.7170557
> 
> # What I don't understand now is why I can't use the total sum of squares 
> tss <- sum(df$w * (df$y - weighted.mean(df$y, df$w))^2)
> 1-rss/tss
[1] 0.5033989
> 
> # The TSS should be equal to RSS + MSS
> rss+mss
[1] 10.9486
> tss
[1] 6.238093
>
```

Comment: Which package is `weighted.mean` from?

Comment: R stats, part of core R.

Comment: Your calculation of `rss` at the end of your code is incorrect.  See lines 8 and 15 of the code for `summary.lm`.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for pointing it out. And it seems that I still have an issue with the tss formula, though I can't spot it. I went and looked at the code for summary.lm. I Can now replicate R's R^2 if I use the mean sum of squares, rather than the total sum of squares. What I still don't understand is why I can't use the TSS. I've edited the question to reflect that.